# If $u_i(\mathbf{x})$ is a vector field, show that $\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$ transforms as a second-rank tensor.

Tags: tensors

> If $u_i(\mathbf{x})$ is a vector field, show that $\frac{\partial
>  u_i}{\partial x_j}$ transforms as a second-rank tensor.

I think is a very easy question I just don't fully understand what the question is asking me to show and so I think seeing a worked example would help me get my head around this a bit better.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\vec{u(\vec{x}})$ is a vector field , this means it can be written in terms of basis vectors and coordinates as : $u^{\nu}(\vec{x})\frac{\partial
}{\partial x^{\nu}}$ (using Einstein summation convention). The $\frac{\partial
}{\partial x^{\nu}}$ are the basis vectors.

The basis vectors $\frac{\partial
}{\partial x^{\nu}}$ transform under a general coordinate transformation
($x^{\lambda} \to x^{\lambda '}$) like a rank one tensor  : $\frac{\partial
}{\partial x^{\nu '}}=\frac{\partial
 x^{\lambda}}{\partial x^{\nu '}}\frac{\partial
}{\partial x^{\lambda}}$

It follows that $u^{\nu '}(\vec{x})\frac{\partial
}{\partial x^{\nu '}}= u^{\nu '}(\vec{x}) \frac{\partial
 x^{\lambda}}{\partial x^{\nu '}}\frac{\partial
}{\partial x^{\lambda}}=u^{\nu }(\vec{x})\frac{\partial
}{\partial x^{\nu }} \implies u^{\nu } \frac{\partial
 x^{\lambda '}}{\partial x^{\nu }} =u^{\lambda ' }$

Update, see comment @ContraKinta below:

$ \implies \frac{\partial
 u^{\lambda ' }}{\partial x^{\rho ' }} = \frac{\partial
}{\partial x^{\rho ' }}(u^{\nu }) \frac{\partial
 x^{\lambda '}}{\partial x^{\nu }} + 
u^{\nu }\frac{\partial
}{\partial x^{\rho ' }}( \frac{\partial
 x^{\lambda '}}{\partial x^{\nu }} )
= \frac{\partial
 u^{\nu }}{\partial x^{\mu }} \cdot \frac{\partial
 x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\rho '  }}   \frac{\partial
 x^{\lambda '}}{\partial x^{\nu }}    + 
u^{\nu }\frac{\partial
 x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\rho '}} \frac{\partial^2 x^{\lambda '}
 }{\partial x^{\mu } x^{\nu }}  $

Now if we demand that the transformation is an affine transformation we have that the second derivatives vanish : $\frac{\partial^2 x^{\lambda '}
}{\partial x^{\mu } x^{\nu }} = 0$.

That means that
$ \frac{\partial
 u^{\lambda ' }}{\partial x^{\rho ' }} 
= \frac{\partial
 u^{\nu }}{\partial x^{\mu }} \cdot \frac{\partial
 x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\rho '  }}   \frac{\partial
 x^{\lambda '}}{\partial x^{\nu }} $ and the partials of the coordinates transform like second rank tensors.

Comment: Thanks, is it fine to take $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}$ as basis vectors?- are they not differential operators?

Comment: @Aka_aka_aka_ak that's just another notation for the basis vectors. The argument reads the same if you replace them by $e_i$.

Comment: Ok great thanks

Comment: This is wrong. First of all, $\partial u^i/\partial x^j$ is only tensorial under affine transformations. Secondly, you need to use the product rule to find the derivative of $\partial x^{\lambda^´}/\partial x^{\nu}$ as well.

Comment: @ContraKinta You're right. Don't know what I was thinking there. In fact I'm not even sure I understand the question now. I think your suggestion of interpreting the transformation as an affine or linear transformation might give the intended answer. I'll try to correct the above.