# How to show that the gradient of a vector field is an order 2 tensor - and what can we learn from doing it wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, tensors

I considered a 3-dimensional vector field, with Cartesian components, $u_i$. My aim was to show that $\partial u_i / \partial x_j$ is an order 2 tensor.

I start with showing that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is a vector. (Skip the next section if we accept this as granted.)

---

*Given that $x_i=L_{ji}x'_j$:
$$\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x'_i}=\frac{\partial(L_{kj}x'_k)}{\partial x'_i}=L_{kj}\frac{\partial x'_k}{\partial x'_i}=L_{kj}\delta _{ki}=L_{ij}$$
Applying chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x'_i}=\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x'_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}=L_{ij}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}$$
This is the transformation property which to be satisfied by a tensor, so we find that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ is a tensor.*

---

So we this knowledge I do:

$$\Big( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\Big)'=\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \Big)'(u_i)'=L_{jq}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_q}L_{ip}u_p=L_{jq}L_{ip}\frac{\partial u_p}{\partial x_q}$$

So $\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$ transforms as a tensor, so I conclude that $\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$ is a tensor.

However if I do:

$$\Big( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} \Big)' = \frac{\partial (u_i)'}{\partial (x_j)'}=\frac{\partial L_{ip}u_p}{\partial L_{jq}x_q}=\frac{L_{ip}}{L_{jq}} \frac{\partial u_p}{\partial x_q}$$

Multiply both sides by $L_{jq}$, then $L_{qj}$:

$$\Big( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} \Big)' = L_{qj}L_{ip}\frac{\partial u_p}{\partial x_q}$$

This is not the same as our previous result (which was: $\Big( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} \Big)' = L_{jq}L_{ip}\frac{\partial u_p}{\partial x_q}$). So using this second method, $\Big( \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j} \Big)$ is not a tensor.

But I know it [is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234517/if-u-i-mathbfx-is-a-vector-field-show-that-frac-partial-u-i-partial).

---

My questions are:

1) Is my first attempt to show that $\frac{u_i}{x_j}$ is a tensor right?

2) Why did the second attempt yielded a result which is so-similar - but wrong - result? What can I learn from the second result? (Ie what step is wrong and why?)